# How to open editable pdf (i,e XFA file) in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

In my iPhone app, there is a requirement that I need to open an editable pdf file and also have to get the data which user enters in that opened file. How to do this? I tried with UIWebView and also directing app to safari in my iPhone app but did not able to that.
Any help along with code is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is going to be very hard, if not impossible, to get working correctly.  If the built in WebKit does not handle it, it probably means writing your own PDF renderer/form handler.

Another possibility is that perhaps you could more simply just parse out the forms to be filled and present them, but that also would involve a subset of PDF parsing.

One last possibility is that you could have the user jump out into an app like PDF Expert (the only iPad app I know that can handle PDF forms) and then somehow get them to where they need to go.

Have you also tried PDF forms in iOS 5?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not try with iOS 5 and have to do it in iOS 4 only.